# To prove that $\ A \subseteq B$ and $A - B = \emptyset$ are logically equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$\ A \subseteq B$ and $A - B = \emptyset$ are logically equivalent

Now we know that if $A=\emptyset$ then $ \forall x \in A P(x)$ is true. So we have $ \forall x \in (A-B) P(x)$ is true. i.e $\forall x (x \in A \land x \notin B) \rightarrow P(x)$.

$\forall x ( (x \notin A \lor x \in B) \lor P(x))$. We can take P(x)= 0 so we have  left with $\forall x ( (x \notin A \lor x \in B) )$ which is what $\ A \subseteq B$  means

Is this correct? Thank you

Comment: Why you start with $A=\emptyset$?

Comment: @zkutch i have stated the result

Comment: But case $A \ne \emptyset$?

Comment: @zkutch I don't understand what you mean. i have replaces A with A - B in the theorem proved in the book by the author

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A \subset B$. So $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$ is true. But this means $x \notin A \lor x \in B$ is true. So statement $x \in A \land x \notin B$ is false and it defined $\emptyset$. Reverse works same.